# Debian MySQL start error

Tags: mysql, debian

I restart my VPS and now I get mysql error when I put in putty

`/etc/init.d/mysql start`

it show

```
[....] Starting mysql (via systemctl): mysql.serviceJob for mysql.service failed. See 'systemctl status mysql.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

failed!

then i try `systemctl status mysql.service`
this show

```
● mysql.service - LSB: Start and stop the mysql database server daemon
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/mysql)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-07-21 12:32:38 CEST; 1min 38s ago
Process: 7762 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/mysql start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 21 12:32:38 Skaci-2 /etc/init.d/mysql[8468]: 0 processes alive and '/usr...n
Jul 21 12:32:38 Skaci-2 /etc/init.d/mysql[8468]: [61B blob data]
Jul 21 12:32:38 Skaci-2 /etc/init.d/mysql[8468]: error: 'Can't connect to lo...'
Jul 21 12:32:38 Skaci-2 /etc/init.d/mysql[8468]: Check that mysqld is runnin...!
Jul 21 12:32:38 Skaci-2 /etc/init.d/mysql[8468]:
Jul 21 12:32:38 Skaci-2 mysql[7762]: Starting MySQL database server: mysqld...d!
Jul 21 12:32:38 Skaci-2 systemd[1]: mysql.service: control process exited, ...=1
Jul 21 12:32:38 Skaci-2 systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Start and stop the...n.
Jul 21 12:32:38 Skaci-2 systemd[1]: Unit mysql.service entered failed state.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

thanks for your advice